# Do the number of contestants in a machine learning competition relate to a lack of confidence in declaring a winner due to multiple comparison errors?

Tags: machine-learning, multiple-comparisons

Machine learning competitions should account for multiple comparison penalties on the hold out validation data used to declare the winner.  As an example, if contestants used the exact same stochastic algorithm like a random forest, their would be a distribution of performance that would depend on the number of contestants.  But the winner would not be truly better than the worst. Is there a way to account for this problem?

Comment: In an ideal world, organizers should account for such issues perfectly, but in practice the empirical best wins. I personally don't have much issues with the current pragmatic approach, because accounting for variability is far from trivial, considering different entries typically use inherently different methods with different bias/variance. Quantifying this is hard and usually relies on some subjective choices. Subjectivity, in my opinion, is even worse than simply choosing the empirical best.

Comment: I agree the current system is fair for declaring a winner, they deserve an award for such an icredible accomplishment - beating everyone on a one shot at a holdout. But to make statements that a machine learning competition has advanced the targeted field of research because one person had performance better than the existing literature should be taken with the grain of salt that with enough entries and natural variability they may have just been the luckiest of all contestants. Do you agree?